# VF page: unknown method

Tags: apex, visualforce

Heres the class

```
  public with sharing class IGT_RemoteSecureLink {

        private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
         public IGT_RemoteSecureLink(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
             {
            this.standardController = standardController;
        }

        public class testing
      {

        IGT_RSS_Interface_SFDC.CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce stub = new IGT_RSS_Interface_SFDC.CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce();
      {
          stub.clientCertName_x = 'External RSS';
      }

        String responseString = new IGT_RSS_Interface_SFDC.CustomBinding_IWCFSalesforce().TestContract('28663' ,'pranay.com');
        }   
    }
```

Heres the VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="IGT_RemoteSecureLink" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton Value="test" action="{!testing}"/>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

ERROR: Unknown method 'CaseStandardController.testing()

So it's not seeing the extension, and when i try to put the extension as the standardController it doesn't let me....

NOTE: we just refreshed our dev instance..I may have modified the case controller/trigger but i don't remember.

This was working prior...

Comment: There's no way this specific code was working previously. `testing` is an inner class, not a Visualforce action method. You must define action methods as methods on your controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
    public class testing
```

To:

```
    public void testing()
```

And it should work just fine. Inner classes need a variable to be called upon, but there's no reason for one here.

Comment: that does it. If i wanted to call on an inner class in the future what document can you point me to that would explain that? Would it be something as simple as getset?

Comment: @ensir You would need a variable, and remember to initialize it in the constructor. `public myClass item { get; set; } public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { item = new myClass(); }` ...